# Net Sales and Operating Income

Tags: annual-report

When reviewing a company's Annual Report, what could explain Net Sales remaining fixed over a two year period, but Operating Income halving over the same period? I was thinking increased costs.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ea2ozvuhqs9xl5/annual-report.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source Net Sales](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/netsales.asp)

> The amount of sales generated by a company after the deduction of returns, allowances for damaged or missing goods and any discounts allowed. The sales number reported on a company's financial statements is a net sales number, reflecting these deductions.

[Source Operating Income](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/netsales.asp)

> The amount of profit realized from a business's operations after taking out operating expenses - such as cost of goods sold (COGS) or wages - and depreciation. Operating income takes the gross income (revenue minus COGS) and subtracts other operating expenses and then removes depreciation. These operating expenses are costs which are incurred from operating activities and include things such as office supplies and heat and power. Operating Income is typically a synonym for earnings before interest and taxes (EBIT) and is also commonly referred to as "operating profit" or "recurring profit".

From this we can only assume, COGS increased, wages(expenses) increased, the company expedited depreciation aggressively. Could be a number of factors. I would check the annual report more vigorously and read between the lines, all the sections in the appendix.